# SSIS Aggregate ADO Net source into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-database, ssis-2012

I have an ADO .Net source that I'm attempting to insert a summary of the number of rows by date.

The source table has over a billion rows. I just want to summarize rowcount for the current month.

This query produces the output I want. What is the best approach to insert the 2 columns into the SQL Server database?

```
SELECT
    g.[ActivityDate], COUNT(*) RecCount
FROM 
    [lab10].[ADONETSource_Integrated] g
JOIN
    vPublic.DimDate AS D ON g.activityDate = d.FullDate
WHERE
    d.FullDate >= CAST(DATEADD(d, (DATEPART(d, DATEADD(m, 0, GETDATE())) * -1) + 1, DATEADD(m, -0, GETDATE())) AS DATE) 
GROUP BY
    g.[ActivityDate]
ORDER BY 
    g.[ActivityDate] DESC

INSERT INTO dbo.OLEDB_Inegrated (activityDate, RecCount)
```

Comment: If this is in the same database, I would argue that the "best approach" is to simply run an `insert/select` in the database. Are these tables in the same database?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly connect source results to destination table insert data in SSIS.

I reproduced the package with sample data with below steps.

1. Created a data flow with source and destination.

[image]

2. Connect source to ADO.NET source table and build your query under SQL Command. (Preview the result for testing).

[image]

3. Create destination table connection and map source to destination columns by connecting source and destination.

[image]

4. Execute the data flow.

[image]

[image]

Reference: [Load data into SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-sql-database-with-ssis?view=sql-server-ver15)